# Chromecast CAF with Widevine DRM

Tags: chromecast, drm, receiver, widevine

I am trying to create a chromecast CAF receiver compatible with DASH+WIDEVINE.

CAF documentation:

```
const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
const playbackConfig = new cast.framework.PlaybackConfig();
// Customize the license url for playback
playbackConfig.licenseUrl = 'http://widevine/yourLicenseServer';
playbackConfig.licenseRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
  requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
};
context.start({playbackConfig: playbackConfig});

// Update playback config licenseUrl according to provided value in load request.
context.getPlayerManager().setMediaPlaybackInfoHandler((loadRequest, playbackConfig) => {
  if (loadRequest.media.customData && loadRequest.media.customData.licenseUrl) {
    playbackConfig.licenseUrl = loadRequest.media.customData.licenseUrl;
  }
  return playbackConfig;
});
```

However, I always get for DASH+WDV videos error HLS_MANIFEST_MASTER 411.
For non DRM content I don't have issues.

Does anyone have a chromecast receiver working with DASH+WDV?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`HLS_MANIFEST_MASTER` suggests that you are giving it a HLS stream instead of a MPEG-DASH stream. So either you are giving it an .m3u8 URL instead of a .mpd URL or you are specifically forcing the Cast SDK to use HLS as the parsing method, instead of MPEG-DASH.

Note that these are the respective mime-types:

- **HLS**: `application/x-mpegurl` or `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl`
- **DASH**: `application/dash+xml`